# How can i solve the warning about TcpListener: Please use TcpListener(IPAddress localaddr, int port) instead?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sockets, networking

I created a new form and at the top i did:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace mws
{
    public partial class Chat : Form
    {
        TcpListener serverSocket = new TcpListener(8888);
```

Under new TcpListener(8888) i see green line and the warning is:

Warning 4   'System.Net.Sockets.TcpListener.TcpListener(int)' is obsolete: '"This method has been deprecated. Please use TcpListener(IPAddress localaddr, int port) instead.

Tried to google but i didn't find any solution.
Tried to do: new TcpListener(8888,21) maybe usig a port but this is a not a solution.

Comment: I guess scrolling down to the [example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c6z86e63%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) was too much?

Comment: The example would have helped if it had been as slim as the answer of @Bull Durham

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
var serverSocket = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 8888);
```