# Handling sockets using internal classes in C#

Tags: c#, sockets

I have created a class that acts as a plugin for another application. It should hold functions to use in the main application. It works in general - that means i can handle usual functions like calculations and even reading files. But i have problems implementing a socket class. I know how to work with sockets in general but in this case i have a problem.

As you may see in the code, there is an internal class `SockAttrib` that should manage the socket creation, the listening and also the messages. Received messages are stored in a dictionary.

```
public class Net : Module {

    private static ReadOnlyCollection<CustomMethod> customMethods;

    internal class SockAttrib {

        public Socket listener;
        public Socket handler;

        /* create the listener */
        public SockAttrib(int port) {
            IPHostEntry host = Dns.GetHostEntry("localhost");
            IPAddress ipAddress = host.AddressList[1];
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, port);          
            try {
                listener = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
                listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
                listener.Listen(10);
                handler = listener.Accept();
            } catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine("socket() " + e); }
        }

        /* listen */
        public SockAttrib() {
                try {
                // Incoming data from the client.    
                string data = "";
                byte[] bytes = null;
                    while (true) {
                        bytes = new byte[1024];
                        int bytesRec = handler.Receive(bytes);
                        data += Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, bytesRec);
                        if (data.IndexOf("<EOF>") > -1)
                        {
                            messages[++idm] = data;
                            //return;
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception e) { Console.WriteLine("listen() "+e); }
        }

        public void Close() {
            handler.Close();
        }
    }

    /* message index */
    private static int idm = 0;
    /* list of messages */
    private static Dictionary<int, String> messages = new Dictionary<int, String>();

    public Net() {               
        if (customMethods != null) return;
        List<CustomMethod> moduleMethods = new List<CustomMethod>();
        moduleMethods.Add(new CustomMethod(typeof(int), "socket", typeof(int)));
        moduleMethods.Add(new CustomMethod(typeof(int), "listen" ));
        moduleMethods.Add(new CustomMethod(typeof(string), "sockread"));
        customMethods = moduleMethods.AsReadOnly();
    }

    public ReadOnlyCollection<CustomMethod> Prototypes {
        get { return customMethods; }
    }

    public object OnMethodInvoke(String functionName, List<object> parameters) {

        if( functionName == "socket") {
            int port = (int)parameters[0];
            SockAttrib sa = new SockAttrib( port );
            return 1;
        }

        if (functionName == "listen") {
            SockAttrib sa = new SockAttrib();
            return 1; 
        }

        if (functionName == "sockread") {
            if (idm > 0) {
                String message = messages[--idm];
                return message;
            } else {
                return "nope";
            }
        }

        return false;
    }

}
```

My problem is the handler. The creation of the socket works but as soon as i connect to the socket using netcat the socket stop listening and i dont get any responses. I hope its not too much code and it should also be easy readable.

Finally the module gets exported as a library (dll) so i cant really give a minimal working example without also posting the module handler.

Comment: That's clear. In `OnMethodInvoke`, you always create a new `SockAttribute` object and discard it again after the constructor completes. Each of these `SockAttribute` objects will have it's own 'handler' and 'listener' fields.

Comment: Can you show me where exactly? Because i created two methods, one including port as argument and the other without any parameters and the one without parameters should not create a new socket, just listen on the existing one and all incoming messages should be stored in the dictionary to read it with `readsock()`. That was my intention.

Comment: Oh (i think) i understand what you mean. Do you mean i should create the socket in `OnMethodInvoke::socket()` and store **the socket** in the dictionary? If so then i dont know how to correctly read from the socket because all "functions" defined in `OnMethodInvoke` were called from the host application and the messages will arrive (maybe - maybe not) faster than the Host application call `readsock()`. Thats why i tried to store all messages in the dictionary.

Comment: So it seems that you have some sort of API implemented by OnMethodInvoke. Could you share a description of this API?

Comment: Do you mean an explaination or the source code? Of course i can share (both, a desc and also source code) but its a quite huge project so i dont know if i should post it here. I thought about posting the Github link but i think this is not allowed.

Comment: If its not allowed i will delete this comment. The Link is https://github.com/zarat/ZVE I think `.\Compiler\CustomMethod.cs`, `.\Runtime\HostFunctionHandler.cs` and `.\Runtime\HostModule.cs` would be relevant to you.

Comment: Perhaps you can just explain what the three functions "socket", "listen" and "sockread" are supposed to do and what the parameters and return values mean?

Comment: The function `socket()` should create a new socket in the background. The socket should listen and store all the received messages in the Dictionary `messages` so that i can read one message after the other using `sockread()`. So the `sockread()` is not really a function to `read()` from the actual socket in real time. It should (simulate) reading and just returns all the stored messages after each other.

Comment: So that when i write a script i can write (pseudocode) `socket(12345); while(true) sockread()`. I have uploaded another file https://github.com/zarat/ZVE/blob/master/Files.cs (a module to read files) i am sure there you can see how it works. Its easy with static files but i totally hang implementing the socket

Comment: 12345 is the port number? And what about the "listen" function? How is the socket closed again? Shall the functions block or not? Sorry, this is currently too vague to be answered.

Comment: Sorry i thought i could manage the rest by myself. For `close()` i will write another `CustomMethod` named `closesock()` or so. It should (in best case) not block, but if it blocks its ok for now. And yes, of course "12345" would be the port number. Anything else you need to know? It should be able to create a socket, listen on that socket, read received messages and finally closing the socket. But i think closing the socket should be the smallest problem :P Thank you very very very much for your patience :D

Comment: The return values doesnt really matter by now but it could be anything. it just have to be defined in `moduleMethods.Add(new CustomMethod(typeof(string), "sockread", typeof(int) ));` the first parameter is the return value, the second is the function name and the others are the parameters that the CustomMethod expects so its variable (could be anything). In case of `sockread()` there must actually not be any parameter at all. I first thought about putting a number to read message #n from the dictionary but i realized thats nonsense, it should return messages as long as there are any

Comment: Did you consider using the [TcpListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener?view=netframework-4.7.2) class instead? It is a bit easier to use.

Comment: That was my first attempt but then visual studio forced me not to use it because its deprecated. I use VS2017. Sorry VS forced me not to use it with just port as parameter. But i had the same logical lack using it

Comment: It's not TcpListener that is deprecated but just the constructor taking only the port number. See  [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28155702/how-can-i-solve-the-warning-about-tcplistener-please-use-tcplisteneripaddress/28155790).

Comment: Yes i have corrected myself, anyways i know how to use sockets in general but have the same logical lack with Socket and TCPListener in this case

Comment: But there are tons of functions in my head that i want to implement so for now i focus on other stuff i think now or later i will find an answer for sockets

Comment: Something seems very wrong with a *constructor* that contains an infinite loop. There's nothing "background" here - both of your constructors are blocking to some extent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Though your requirements are still a bit fuzzy, I will give it a try.

First I would recommend to create a class containing the core functionality of your TCP server. This makes it easier to unit-test your code and to adapt it to changing requirements.

```
/// <summary>
/// This class encapsulates the TCP server
/// </summary>
public class Server : IDisposable
{
    private static TcpListener _listener;
    private static TcpClient _client;
    private static NetworkStream _stream;
    private static byte[] _buffer;
    private static readonly StringBuilder _receivedText = new StringBuilder();
    private const string EOF = "<EOF>";

    /// <summary>
    /// Starts listening on the specified port
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="port">The port number</param>
    public Server(int port)
    {
        _listener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, port);
        _listener.Start();
        _listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(Accepted, null);
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (_client != null)
        {
            _client.Dispose();
        }
        if (_listener != null)
        {
            _listener.Stop();
        }
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Returns any text that has been sent via TCP to the port specified in the constructor.
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>The received text, or null if no (complete) text has been received yet.</returns>
    /// <remarks>
    /// The method returns the next text delimited by "&lt;EOF&gt;".
    /// </remarks>
    public string Read()
    {
        lock (_receivedText)
        {
            var receivedText = _receivedText.ToString();
            var eofIndex = receivedText.IndexOf(EOF);
            if (eofIndex < 0)
                return null; // no (complete) text has been received yet
            var result = receivedText.Substring(0, eofIndex);
            _receivedText.Remove(0, eofIndex + EOF.Length);
            return result;
        }
    }

    // called whenever a client has connected to our server.
    private static void Accepted(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        _client = _listener.EndAcceptTcpClient(ar);
        _stream = _client.GetStream();
        _buffer = new byte[4096];
        _stream.BeginRead(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, Read, null);
    }

    // called whenever data has arrived or if the client closed the TCP connection
    private static void Read(IAsyncResult ar)
    {
        var bytesReceived = _stream.EndRead(ar);
        if (bytesReceived == 0)
        {
            // TCP connection closed
            _client.Close();
            _client = null;
            _stream.Dispose();
            _stream = null;
            // prepare for accepting the next TCP connection
            _listener.BeginAcceptTcpClient(Accepted, null);
            return;
        }

        lock (_receivedText)
        {
            _receivedText.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(_buffer, 0, bytesReceived));
        }

        // prepare for reading more
        _stream.BeginRead(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length, Read, null);
    }
}
```

Integrating this into your `Net` class should then be fairly simple:

```
// static or not? Depends on your "Module plugin" architecture
private static Server _server;

public object OnMethodInvoke(String functionName, List<object> parameters)
{
    if (functionName == "socket")
    {
        if (_server != null)
        {
            // oops, already open
            return 0;
        }
        int port = (int)parameters[0];
        _server = new Server(port);
        return 1;
    }

    if (functionName == "sockread")
    {
        if (_server != null)
        {
            return _server.Read() ?? "nope";
        }
        else
        {
            return "nope";
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much its too close to my needs, i just recognized i have to find another approach for my EOF crap